# How to pass an array in an url query parameter using nsurl in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

The API need to pass an array in an url query parameter, how to acheive this in iOS?

I only know how to pass a single vaue, like the API below : `?title=Design Milk&id=feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/design-milk`

API sample:

```
  "title": "Design Milk",
  "id": "feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/design-milk",
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": "user/c805fcbf-3acf-4302-a97e-d82f9d7c897f/category/design",
      "label": "design"
    },
    {
      "id": "user/c805fcbf-3acf-4302-a97e-d82f9d7c897f/category/weekly",
      "label": "weekly"
    },
    {
      "id": "user/c805fcbf-3acf-4302-a97e-d82f9d7c897f/category/global.must",
      "label": "must reads"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: @Zaph Yes, this is a http POST request, can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: You need to set your parameters in the request body rather than putting them as URL parameters

Comment: Suggestion: change the question title, it states: "query parameter".

Comment: @Stonz2 Does your means is put all data into a nsdictionary, convert it to nsdata object, then call setHTTPBody method?

Comment: put the array (and all other parameters/values) into the request's body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a collection and then use `NSJSONSerialization` to create JSON data representation. Use the resulting data as the POST data.

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
  @"title": @"Design Milk",
  @"id": @"feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/design-milk",
  @"categories": @[
          @{
              @"id": @"user/c805fcbf-3acf-4302-a97e-d82f9d7c897f/category/design",
              @"label": @"design"
              },
          @{
              @"id": @"user/c805fcbf-3acf-4302-a97e-d82f9d7c897f/category/weekly",
              @"label": @"weekly"
              },
          @{
              @"id": @"user/c805fcbf-3acf-4302-a97e-d82f9d7c897f/category/global.must",
              @"label": @"must reads"
              }
          ]
};

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictData options:0 error:&error];
```