# How to pass an Array of IDs in parameter in Json Request

Tags: ios, iphone, json, xcode

I have a JSON Request and some parameter...I need to pass an array in one of these parameters...How?

There's my current request...I have 3 parameters: latitude, longitude and Array: Array must be an array of ids (int)

Array:  `NSArray arrayIds = [NSArrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];`

```
  -(void) listarAtracoesBusca
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    self.listaAtracoes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.indiceAtracaoAtual = 0;
    NSString *urlStr = @"";
    float latitude = 0.0;
    float longitude = 0.0;

    if(appDelegate.latitudeAtual)
        latitude = appDelegate.latitudeAtual;
    if(appDelegate.longitudeAtual)
        longitude = appDelegate.longitudeAtual;

    [self validarCamposBusca];

    urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://host:3000/api/ params?latitude=%f&longitude=%f&array=", latitude, longitude, arrayIds];


    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:10.0];
    [request setValue:@"haadushdiuashud" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-User-Authorization"];
    NSString *basicAuthCredentials = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"user", @"pass"];
    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", AFBase64EncodedStringFromString(basicAuthCredentials)];

    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                               //Do Stuff

                               if (data.length > 0 && error == nil)
                               {
}
                               else {
                                   NSLog(@"erro: %@", error.description);
                               }
                           }];
}
```

Comment: What are the values you have in array? What is the URL you are trying to form?

Comment: Any array: NSArray arrayIds = [NSArrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil]; for example

Comment: Are you passing this JSON as a body of this request? Have you looked at `NSJSONSerialization`?

Comment: Ok. What is your exact URL you are trying to form?

Comment: The url is available only locally

Comment: Thats ok. I'm asking what you are trying to form with this.
`urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://host:3000/api/ params?latitude=%f&longitude=%f&array=", latitude, longitude, array];` How your URL should be look like to get it work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to achieve some thing like query url then you can use NSURLQueryItem that will represent the single key/value pair for query portion of URL.

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"];
NSURLQueryItem *search = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"q" value:@"ios"];
NSURLQueryItem *count = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"count" value:@"10"];
components.queryItems = @[ search, count ];
NSURL *url = components.URL; // http://stackoverflow.com?q=ios&count=10
```

Otherwise you need to pass the JSON as body of your request using NSJSONSerialization. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162871/how-to-pass-an-array-in-an-url-query-parameter-using-nsurl-in-objective-c) for more details.